# focus only working with alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

I have the following, rather simple function:

```
function takeFocus() {
   setTimeout(function(){window.focus();alert("OK");},1000);
}
```

This is within the JavaScript of a window I have opened from another window.

When the user re-opens the sub-window, I want to switch to it, and bring it to the front, without reloading it. Calling `takeFocus()` as above works just fine, but it throws up the prompt, which I don't want.

When I remove the alert, the background window stays in the background! How can I make it work?

I have tried all sorts of ways to do this, and so far I have failed.

jQuery is available. Writing for modern browsers in HTML5.

Comment: More information: I removed the window.focus() in the above routine, keeping the alert - and it brought the window to the foreground. It appears that window.focus() does nothing in this situation. Still don't understand how to correct the code though :(

Answer (score 0):

Is this code in the sub-window file?
Try use the focus in the main page like this:

```
function newPopup(url) {
popupWindow = window.open(
url,'popUpWindow3','height=500,width=900,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no');
popupWindow.focus();
}
```

Comment: That will indeed bring the window to the front, but it also reloads the window with the URL, which is what I am trying to avoid. So far my testing has shown that open will always reload the content - although I can get the content to load in the same window.

Comment: Right.
Maybe you can save the page url in an array object and verify before call the function, if it not exists: create and focus else: focus.
    
    var popups_holder = new Object();
    function popupOpen(target_url, window_name){
 
        if(typeof(popups_holder[window_name]) == undefined || typeof(popups_holder[window_name]) == 'undefined'){
    var w = window.open(target_url, window_name, 'width=450, height=450');
    popups_holder[window_name] = w;
    }else{
        popups_holder[window_name].focus();
    } 
}

[link](http://mihaifrentiu.com/how-to-focus-a-popup-without-reloading-it)

Comment: Leandro, That is where I started. Found the "popups_holder[window_name].focus();" did not work so tried to schedule it, and then wrote the takeFocus() routine to schedule it in the right context. I still haven't found a way to bring the sub-window to the foreground without refreshing the URL or using an alert.

Answer (score 0):

I have half an answer. By using this code to open the window, I get the behaviour I need in Chrome. Sadly FireFox 23.01 and IE 10 are still ignoring the win.focus().

```
function openWin(ID) { // open workshop ID in another window
   var URL = '/chatroom.php?ID='+ID;
   var name = 'Chat'+ID;   // so if you open it twice it reopens the window.
   var win = window.open('',name); // no URL - won't refresh
   if (win.location == "about:blank") { // new open
      win.location.href = URL; 
      windows[windows.length] = win; // store for later.
  }  
  win.focus();
}
```

FF and IE open the window OK the first time, and they don't refresh and lose the data on the second pass, but they don't bring it to the foreground either :(